# Как сохранить переменную из ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

У меня есть страничка index1.php, там выполняется ajax запрос. Переменная передается на  index2.php. Как можно сохранить переменную  в index2.php. Попробовал сохранить в сессиях не получилась.

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['asd']=$_POST['name'];
?>
```

Comment: Проверьте что возвращает $_POST['name']. И лучше, с начало записывать в сессию, а потом выводить результат.

Comment: в index1.php возвращает какую та строку. Там все нармально. Но мне надо еще сохранить переменную которую передается с методом post. После того как он вернул значение, захожу в index2.php но там пусто.

Comment: в index2.php нужно так-же написать session_start(), что бы получить доступ к суперглобальному массиву $_SESSION.  
Ваш код у меня работает, так что хотелось бы больше кода.

Comment: наоборот. Этот код  и так то записан в index2.